# Vulkan рисует одним цветом

Tags: c++, графика, vulkan

Проблема с рисовкой вулканом. Какой бы цвет не задавал в фрагментном шейдере - либо ничего не выводит, либо выводит только красный треугольник. Как будто не поддерживает другие цвета.

```
    #version 450
    #extension  GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects: enable

    layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

    void main()
    {
        outColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
```

Код на С++

```cpp
    #define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR 
    #define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN

    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>

    #define assert_vulkan(expr) (assert(!expr))

    VkInstance vkInstance;
    VkDevice vkDevice;
    VkPhysicalDevice gpu;
    VkSurfaceKHR surface;
    VkSwapchainKHR swapChain;
    GLFWwindow* window;
    VkShaderModule shaderModuleVert;
    VkShaderModule shaderModuleFrag;
    VkPipelineLayout pipelineLayout;
    VkRenderPass vkRenderPass;
    VkPipeline pipeline;
    VkQueue queue;
    VkCommandPool commandPool;
    std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> commandBuffers;

    VkSemaphore semaphoreImageAvailable;
    VkSemaphore semaphoreRenderFinished;

    uint32_t currentQueueFamily = 0;

    VkFormat currentFormat = VkFormat::VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;

    std::vector<VkImageView> imageViews;
    std::vector<VkFramebuffer> frameBuffers;

    const int width = 400;
    const int height = 300;

    void printStates(VkPhysicalDevice& device);

    std::string readFile(const std::string fileName) {
        std::ifstream inputFile(fileName, std::ios::binary);
        assert(inputFile.is_open());
        return std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    }

    void startGlfw() {
        glfwInit();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Vulkan", 0, 0);
    }

    void createShaderModule(std::string code, VkShaderModule* shaderModule) {
        VkShaderModuleCreateInfo shaderModuleCreateInfo{};
        shaderModuleCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
        shaderModuleCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        shaderModuleCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        shaderModuleCreateInfo.codeSize = code.length();
        shaderModuleCreateInfo.pCode = (uint32_t*)code.data();
        auto res = vkCreateShaderModule(vkDevice, &shaderModuleCreateInfo, 0, shaderModule);
        assert_vulkan(res);
    }

    void startVulkan() {
        VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
        appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        appInfo.pNext = 0;
        appInfo.pApplicationName = "Vulkan";
        appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 0);
        appInfo.pEngineName = "Start engine";
        appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.apiVersion = VK_VERSION_1_0;

        uint32_t amountOfLayers = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&amountOfLayers, 0);
        std::vector<VkLayerProperties> layouts(amountOfLayers);
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&amountOfLayers, layouts.data());

        std::cout << "Layouts count: " << amountOfLayers << std::endl;
        int i = 0;
        for (auto& layout : layouts) {
            std::cout << "Layout #" << i + 1 << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Name: " << layout.layerName << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Spec version: " << layout.specVersion << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Impl version: " << layout.implementationVersion << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Description: " << layout.description << std::endl;
            i++;
        }

        uint32_t nExtensions = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(0, &nExtensions, 0);
        std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> allExtensions(nExtensions);
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(0, &nExtensions, allExtensions.data());

        std::cout << "Extensions count: " << nExtensions << std::endl;

        i = 0;
        for (auto& ext : allExtensions) {
            std::cout << "Extension #" << i + 1 << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Name: " << ext.extensionName << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Spec version: " << ext.specVersion << std::endl;
            i++;
        }

        std::vector<const char*> validationLayers = {
            "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"
        };

        uint32_t amountGlfwExtensions = 0;
        auto glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&amountGlfwExtensions);


        VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo{};
        instanceCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
        instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        instanceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        instanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = validationLayers.size();
        instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
        instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;
        instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = amountGlfwExtensions;

        auto res = vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, 0, &vkInstance);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        res = glfwCreateWindowSurface(vkInstance, window, 0, &surface);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        uint32_t pDevicesCount = 0;
        vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vkInstance, &pDevicesCount, 0);

        std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> physicalDevices(pDevicesCount);
        res = vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vkInstance, &pDevicesCount, physicalDevices.data());
        assert_vulkan(res);

        for (auto& pDevice : physicalDevices) {
            printStates(pDevice);
        }


        VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo deviceQueueCreateInfo{};
        deviceQueueCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
        deviceQueueCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        deviceQueueCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        deviceQueueCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = currentQueueFamily;
        deviceQueueCreateInfo.queueCount = 4;
        deviceQueueCreateInfo.pQueuePriorities = new float[4]{ 1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f };

        VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures usedFeatures = {};

        std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = {
            VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME
        };

        VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceCreateInfo{};
        deviceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
        deviceCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        deviceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        deviceCreateInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
        deviceCreateInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = &deviceQueueCreateInfo;
        deviceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
        deviceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = 0;
        deviceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = deviceExtensions.size();
        deviceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = deviceExtensions.data();
        deviceCreateInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &usedFeatures;

        res = vkCreateDevice(physicalDevices[0], &deviceCreateInfo, 0, &vkDevice);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        vkGetDeviceQueue(vkDevice, 0, 0, &queue);

        VkBool32 isSupport = false;
        res = vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(physicalDevices[0], 0, surface, &isSupport);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        if (!isSupport) {
            std::cerr << "Surface not supported!\n";
            __debugbreak();
        }

        VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchainCreateInfo{};
        swapchainCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
        swapchainCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        swapchainCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        swapchainCreateInfo.surface = surface;
        swapchainCreateInfo.minImageCount = 3;
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageFormat = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageColorSpace = VK_COLORSPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR;
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageExtent = VkExtent2D{ width, height };
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1;
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
        swapchainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1;
        swapchainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = &currentQueueFamily;
        swapchainCreateInfo.preTransform = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR;
        swapchainCreateInfo.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
        swapchainCreateInfo.presentMode = VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR;
        swapchainCreateInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE;
        swapchainCreateInfo.oldSwapchain = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

        res = vkCreateSwapchainKHR(vkDevice, &swapchainCreateInfo, 0, &swapChain);
        assert_vulkan(res);


        uint32_t nImagesInSwapChain = 0;
        vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(vkDevice, swapChain, &nImagesInSwapChain, 0);
        std::vector<VkImage> vkImages(nImagesInSwapChain);
        res = vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(vkDevice, swapChain, &nImagesInSwapChain, vkImages.data());
        assert_vulkan(res);

        imageViews.resize(nImagesInSwapChain);

        for (i = 0; i < nImagesInSwapChain; i++) {

            VkImageViewCreateInfo imageViewCreateInfo{};
            imageViewCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
            imageViewCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
            imageViewCreateInfo.flags = 0;
            imageViewCreateInfo.image = vkImages[i];
            imageViewCreateInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
            imageViewCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
            imageViewCreateInfo.components = { VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY, VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY ,VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY ,VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY };
            imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
            imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
            imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
            imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
            imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

            res = vkCreateImageView(vkDevice, &imageViewCreateInfo, 0, &imageViews[i]);
            assert_vulkan(res);
        }


        auto shaderCodeVert = readFile("vert.spv");
        auto shaderCodeFrag = readFile("frag.spv");

        std::cout << shaderCodeFrag.length() << std::endl;
        std::cout << shaderCodeVert.length() << std::endl;

        createShaderModule(shaderCodeFrag, &shaderModuleFrag);
        createShaderModule(shaderCodeVert, &shaderModuleVert);

        VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo piplineShaderCreateInfoVert{};
        piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.pNext = 0;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.flags = 0;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.module = shaderModuleVert;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.pName = "main";
        piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.pSpecializationInfo = 0;

        VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag{};
        piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.pNext = 0;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.flags = 0;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.module = shaderModuleFrag;
        piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.pName = "main";
        piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.pSpecializationInfo = 0;

        VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[]{ piplineShaderCreateInfoVert , piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag };

        VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo inputVertexCreateInfo{};
        inputVertexCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
        inputVertexCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        inputVertexCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        inputVertexCreateInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 0;
        inputVertexCreateInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = 0;
        inputVertexCreateInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 0;
        inputVertexCreateInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = 0;

        VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssemblyCreateInfo{};
        inputAssemblyCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
        inputAssemblyCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        inputAssemblyCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        inputAssemblyCreateInfo.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
        inputAssemblyCreateInfo.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

        VkViewport vkViewPort;
        vkViewPort.x = 0;
        vkViewPort.y = 0;
        vkViewPort.width = width;
        vkViewPort.height = height;
        vkViewPort.minDepth = 0;
        vkViewPort.maxDepth = 1;

        VkRect2D scissor;
        scissor.offset = { 0,0 };
        scissor.extent = { width, height };

        VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportStateCreateInfo{};
        viewportStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
        viewportStateCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        viewportStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        viewportStateCreateInfo.viewportCount = 1;
        viewportStateCreateInfo.pViewports = &vkViewPort;
        viewportStateCreateInfo.scissorCount = 1;
        viewportStateCreateInfo.pScissors = &scissor;

        VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo{};
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasConstantFactor = 0;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasClamp = 0;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasSlopeFactor = 0;
        pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.lineWidth = 1;

        VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo{};
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.minSampleShading = 1.0f;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.pSampleMask = 0;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.alphaToCoverageEnable = VK_FALSE;
        pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.alphaToOneEnable = VK_FALSE;

        VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState{};
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
        pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT;

        VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlendCreateInfo{};
        colorBlendCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_NO_OP;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.pAttachments = &pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[0] = 0;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[1] = 0;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[2] = 0;
        colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[3] = 0;

        VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutCreateInfo{};
        pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
        pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setLayoutCount = 0;
        pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pSetLayouts = 0;
        pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;
        pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pPushConstantRanges = 0;

        res = vkCreatePipelineLayout(vkDevice, &pipelineLayoutCreateInfo, 0, &pipelineLayout);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        VkAttachmentDescription attachmentDescription{};
        attachmentDescription.flags = 0;
        attachmentDescription.format = currentFormat;
        attachmentDescription.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
        attachmentDescription.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
        attachmentDescription.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
        attachmentDescription.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
        attachmentDescription.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
        attachmentDescription.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
        attachmentDescription.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

        VkAttachmentReference attachmenetReference{};
        attachmenetReference.attachment = 0;
        attachmenetReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

        VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription{};
        subpassDescription.flags = 0;
        subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
        subpassDescription.inputAttachmentCount = 0;
        subpassDescription.pInputAttachments = 0;
        subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
        subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = &attachmenetReference;
        subpassDescription.pResolveAttachments = 0;
        subpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment = 0;
        subpassDescription.preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
        subpassDescription.pPreserveAttachments = 0;

        VkSubpassDependency subpassDependency{};
        subpassDependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
        subpassDependency.dstSubpass = 0;
        subpassDependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
        subpassDependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
        subpassDependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
        subpassDependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
        subpassDependency.dependencyFlags = 0;

        VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassCreateInfo{};
        renderPassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
        renderPassCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        renderPassCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        renderPassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
        renderPassCreateInfo.pAttachments = &attachmentDescription;
        renderPassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
        renderPassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
        renderPassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
        renderPassCreateInfo.pDependencies = &subpassDependency;

        res = vkCreateRenderPass(vkDevice, &renderPassCreateInfo, 0, &vkRenderPass);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineCreateInfo{};
        pipelineCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        pipelineCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        pipelineCreateInfo.stageCount = 2;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pVertexInputState = &inputVertexCreateInfo;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssemblyCreateInfo;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pTessellationState = 0;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pViewportState = &viewportStateCreateInfo;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pRasterizationState = &pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pMultisampleState = &pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pDepthStencilState = 0;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlendCreateInfo;
        pipelineCreateInfo.pDynamicState = 0;
        pipelineCreateInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
        pipelineCreateInfo.renderPass = vkRenderPass;
        pipelineCreateInfo.subpass = 0;
        pipelineCreateInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
        pipelineCreateInfo.basePipelineIndex = -1;

        res = vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(vkDevice, 0, 1, &pipelineCreateInfo, 0, &pipeline);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        frameBuffers.resize(nImagesInSwapChain);

        for (i = 0; i < nImagesInSwapChain; i++) {
            VkFramebufferCreateInfo frameBufferCreateInfo{};
            frameBufferCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
            frameBufferCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
            frameBufferCreateInfo.flags = 0;
            frameBufferCreateInfo.renderPass = vkRenderPass;
            frameBufferCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
            frameBufferCreateInfo.pAttachments = &imageViews[i];
            frameBufferCreateInfo.width = width;
            frameBufferCreateInfo.height = height;
            frameBufferCreateInfo.layers = 1;

            res = vkCreateFramebuffer(vkDevice, &frameBufferCreateInfo, 0, &frameBuffers[i]);
            assert_vulkan(res);
        }

        VkCommandPoolCreateInfo commandPoolCreateInfo{};
        commandPoolCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
        commandPoolCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        commandPoolCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        commandPoolCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = currentQueueFamily;

        res = vkCreateCommandPool(vkDevice, &commandPoolCreateInfo, 0, &commandPool);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo commandBufferAllocateInfo{};
        commandBufferAllocateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
        commandBufferAllocateInfo.pNext = 0;
        commandBufferAllocateInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
        commandBufferAllocateInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
        commandBufferAllocateInfo.commandBufferCount = nImagesInSwapChain;

        commandBuffers.resize(nImagesInSwapChain);
        res = vkAllocateCommandBuffers(vkDevice, &commandBufferAllocateInfo, commandBuffers.data());
        assert_vulkan(res);

        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo commandBufferBeginInfo{};
        commandBufferBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
        commandBufferBeginInfo.pNext = 0;
        commandBufferBeginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;
        commandBufferBeginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < nImagesInSwapChain; i++) {
            res = vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i], &commandBufferBeginInfo);
            assert_vulkan(res);

            VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo{};
            renderPassBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
            renderPassBeginInfo.pNext = 0;
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass = vkRenderPass;
            renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer = frameBuffers[i];
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0,0 };
            renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent = { width, height };
            VkClearValue clearValue = { 0,0,0,1 };
            renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
            renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues = &clearValue;

            vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

            vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline);
            vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], 3, 1, 0, 0);

            vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);

            res = vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i]);
            assert_vulkan(res);
        }

        VkSemaphoreCreateInfo semaphoreCreateInfo{};
        semaphoreCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SEMAPHORE_CREATE_INFO;
        semaphoreCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
        semaphoreCreateInfo.flags = 0;

        res = vkCreateSemaphore(vkDevice, &semaphoreCreateInfo, 0, &semaphoreImageAvailable);
        assert_vulkan(res);
        res = vkCreateSemaphore(vkDevice, &semaphoreCreateInfo, 0, &semaphoreRenderFinished);
        assert_vulkan(res);
    }

    void drawFrame() {

        uint32_t imageIndex;
        auto res = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(vkDevice, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, semaphoreImageAvailable, 0, &imageIndex);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
        submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
        submitInfo.pNext = 0;
        submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = &semaphoreImageAvailable;
        VkPipelineStageFlags waitStageMask[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
        submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStageMask;
        submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[imageIndex];
        submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = &semaphoreRenderFinished;

        res = vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, 0);
        assert_vulkan(res);

        VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo;
        presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
        presentInfo.pNext = 0;
        presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = &semaphoreRenderFinished;
        presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pSwapchains = &swapChain;
        presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;
        presentInfo.pResults = 0;

        res = vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, &presentInfo);
        assert_vulkan(res);
    }

    void gameLoop() {
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
            drawFrame();
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне представляется, что проблема заключается в маске записи в экранный буфер, разрешающей вывод только красного канала:

```
pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT;
```

вместо

```
pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT
    bitor VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT
    bitor VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT;
```

Comment: Да, в этом проблема! Спасибо!)